How to set mailbox email signature with Powershell and Roaming signatures?
What i am trying to achieve is to have all users use a unified email signature template in a cloud/O365 environment. I came across this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-mailboxmessageconfiguration?view=exchange-ps
which explicitely says

Note: This parameter doesn't work if the Outlook roaming signatures feature is enabled in your cloud-based organization.

If the users can set their signature in Outlook itself, and it then synchronizes with OWA and other user's devices, how can an admin set the signature for the user on the "server", to let it then synchronize to all user's devices?
The documentation then says

Admins can now temporarily disable roaming signatures without opening a support ticket by using the PostponeRoamingSignaturesUntilLater parameter on the Set-OrganizationConfig cmdlet.

but temporarily and UntilLater sounds to me that this could stop working at any time and is therefore not very future-proof.
Even if i disable it, i actually didn't find a way to set it locally in Outlook, other than some nasty registry and XML hacks (if you also want to include a company logo in the sig).

A signature can be AUTO or not AUTO.  If it is AUTO, you do not want to add a 2nd signature.  Roaming signatures the key is stored on the Outlook server instead of on the devices so all devices will use one key (see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outlook-roaming-signatures-420c2995-1f57-4291-9004-8f6f97c54d15?ui=en-us&rs=en-gb&ad=gb).  The admin can temporarily disable the signature on the outlook server and enable the signature stored locally.

But how do I change the roaming signature that is stored on the server?

See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/location-path-for-the-signatures-in-the-new/06dfd29d-fba2-4343-a2f6-08e94f8afc6a
